# setImageResource for an ImageView from another ImageView

Tags: android

Strange request here, but is there any way you set an imageview to hold the same drawable as another imageview by getting it from the original imageview. what i mean is:

```
ImageView image1 = new ImageView(this);
          image1.setimageResource(R.drawable.blah1);

ImageView image2 = new ImageView(this);

//now i want something like this, which doesn't work. i  want to get it from image1
image2.setImageResource(image1.getDrawable());
```

so please how can i achieve this from image1?.. Thank you :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `setImageDrawable` instead of `setImageResource`

Comment: Hmm.. thanks it worked!. i had thought i tried that. will check it in my code tommorrow. thanks once again

Answer (score 1):

For setting Image Resources from another image view

You need to use two methods of ImagView

- setImageDrawable()
- getDrawable()

Your code is all perfect except one error

You need to use **setImageDrawable()** in place of **setImageResource()**

following is your code implemention using above methods with correction

```
ImageView image1 = new ImageView(this);
image1.setimageResource(R.drawable.blah1);

ImageView image2 = new ImageView(this);

// just change this to setImageDrawable
image2.setImageDrawable(image1.getDrawable());
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.